Django - Editing/updating records on formset triggering duplicate error
In Django, I have this FBV that updates selected records:
def edit_selected_accountsplan(request):

    selected_items_str = request.GET.get('items', '')
    selected_items = [int(item) for item in selected_items_str.split(',') if item.isdigit()]
    accountsplan_to_edit = AccountsPlan.objects.filter(id__in=selected_items)

    AccountsPlanFormSet = formset_factory(form=AccountsPlanForm, extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AccountsPlanFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():

            for form, accountplan in zip(formset, accountsplan_to_edit):

                accountplan.subgroup = form.cleaned_data['subgroup']
                accountplan.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                accountplan.active = form.cleaned_data['active']
                accountplan.save()

            return redirect('confi:list_accountsplan')

    else:

        initial_data = []

        for accountplan in accountsplan_to_edit:
            initial_data.append({
                'subgroup': accountplan.subgroup,
                'name': accountplan.name,
                'active': accountplan.active,
            })

        formset = AccountsPlanFormSet(initial=initial_data)

    return render(request, 'confi/pages/accountsplan/edit_selected_accountsplan.html', context={
        'formset': formset,
    })

Everything works as expected (the page loads, the form is filled correctly etc.) except when saving the data. The 'name' field is defined as unique in the database, so when I try to change other fields but don't change the name, it gives me a duplicate error. If I change the name to anything else that is not already in the database, it updates the current name correctly, so it's not creating a new record. I've tried to change the loop block to this just to see if I could save:
    for form, accountplan in zip(formset, accountsplan_to_edit):

        form.instance = accountplan
        form.save()

    return redirect('confi:list_accountsplan')

But again, the duplicate error is triggered. I don't understand why this is happening. If I'm just updating the current record, why is it giving a duplicate error? How can I have this updated correctly?
Here's the model code:
class AccountsPlan (models.Model):

    subgroup = models.ForeignKey(Subgroups, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "An account with this name already exists. Please, choose another.",
        }
    )

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    show_acc = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    show_man = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'AccountPlans'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


Turns out there's a much better way to achieve what I want by using a model formset. This way no initial data or messing with forms is necessary. Here's my implementation, based on the docs:
def edit_selected_accountsplan(request):

    selected_items_str = request.GET.get('items', '')
    selected_items = [int(item) for item in selected_items_str.split(',') if item.isdigit()]

    AccountsPlanFormSet = modelformset_factory(AccountsPlan, fields=('subgroup', 'name', 'active'), extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AccountsPlanFormSet(request.POST, queryset=AccountsPlan.objects.filter(id__in=selected_items))
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

            return redirect('confi:list_accountsplan')

    else:

        formset = AccountsPlanFormSet(queryset=AccountsPlan.objects.filter(id__in=selected_items))

    return render(request, 'confi/pages/accountsplan/edit_selected_accountsplan.html', context={
        'formset': formset,
    })

And in the template, I just had to add the form.id to the form, as stated in the docs:
{% for form in formset %}
{{ form.id }} # added this
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.subgroup }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.active }}</td>               
    <td>
        {% if form.errors %}                
            {% for error in form.errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}                  
       {% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>
  


The reason that this will fail is because the ModelForm thinks you are creating a new record, and thus it will check if an object with the given name already exists, and if so, it of course finds out the name already exists, hence the form is not valid.
Check this thread out
Also you may avoid the validation on the instance itself using clean method. you add this to your form class:
def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data['name']
    existing = AccountsPlan.objects.filter(name=name).exclude(id=self.instance.id)
    if existing.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("This name is already in use.")
    return name


Doesn't the second block passes the instance, like described in the thread you suggested?

By second block, you mean "else" condition? It is not that one.
"form = CourseCreateForm(request.POST, instance=course)" -> here you pass the instance. Check my updated answer, please. I believe it may solve it better.

I meant in my question. I've tried to use form.instance = accoutplan, which I assume is the same as suggested in the thread. Thanks for updating your answer. I'll try the code, although I'm not sure what is it doing. If it is excluding the record and recreating it, I can't use it because AccountsPlan is a fk to other models.

Clean method is for doing extra/custom validation, which overrides the default. What it means that, if you customize to exclude the "name", it will not return the uniqueness check. Here is more about it:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Thanks. I did know the clean method, but I didn't know that you could use to bypass checks like this. I've tried your code but it also triggers the validation error if I don't change the name.
